# FreeSwitch very slow

Tags: sip, voip, freeswitch

I've installed a default out of the box FreeSwitch instance but when I try to make an internal call (extension to extension) it take around 12 seconds before the call is established and I can hear the ring tone.

When I look at the log I see the connection request almost instantly but then no activities and after 10 seconds or more the call starts and I hear the phone ringing.
Here is the log file it it helps, please see the 10 seconds delay between 130:08:07 to 13:08:17.

```
freeswitch@vps-1170411-23979.manage.myhosting.com> 2015-09-26 13:07:41.591949 [CONSOLE] mod_voicemail.c:4091 Event Thread Started  
2015-09-26 13:08:02.171949 [NOTICE] switch_channel.c:1075 New Channel sofia/internal/1001@168.144.85.16 [25229804-6471-11e5-9558-f1a7477c5309]  
2015-09-26 13:08:07.331948 [INFO] mod_dialplan_xml.c:635 Processing BSmarter.CA <1001>->1000 in context default  
2015-09-26 13:08:07.331948 [CRIT] mod_dptools.c:1670 WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING   
2015-09-26 13:08:07.331948 [CRIT] mod_dptools.c:1670 Open /usr/local/freeswitch/conf/vars.xml and change the default_password.  
2015-09-26 13:08:07.331948 [CRIT] mod_dptools.c:1670 Once changed type 'reloadxml' at the console.  
2015-09-26 13:08:07.331948 [CRIT] mod_dptools.c:1670 WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING   
2015-09-26 13:08:17.371961 [INFO] switch_ivr_async.c:3932 Bound B-Leg: *1 execute_extension::dx XML features  
2015-09-26 13:08:17.371961 [INFO] switch_ivr_async.c:3932 Bound B-Leg: *2 record_session::/usr/local/freeswitch/recordings/1001.2015-09-26-13-08-17.wav  
2015-09-26 13:08:17.371961 [INFO] switch_ivr_async.c:3932 Bound B-Leg: *3 execute_extension::cf XML features  
2015-09-26 13:08:17.371961 [INFO] switch_ivr_async.c:3932 Bound B-Leg: *4 execute_extension::att_xfer XML features  
2015-09-26 13:08:17.391951 [NOTICE] switch_channel.c:1075 New Channel sofia/internal/1000@99.226.75.129:63329 [2e34333a-6471-11e5-957b-f1a7477c5309]  
2015-09-26 13:08:17.571984 [NOTICE] sofia.c:6760 Ring-Ready sofia/internal/1000@99.226.75.129:63329!  
2015-09-26 13:08:17.591949 [INFO] switch_ivr_originate.c:1193 Sending early media  
2015-09-26 13:08:17.591949 [INFO] switch_core_media.c:5395 Activating RTCP PORT 4003  
2015-09-26 13:08:17.591949 [NOTICE] sofia_media.c:92 Pre-Answer sofia/internal/1001@168.144.85.16!  
2015-09-26 13:08:18.631986 [NOTICE] sofia.c:7580 Hangup   sofia/internal/1001@168.144.85.16 [CS_EXECUTE] [ORIGINATOR_CANCEL]
```

Any idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This pause was introduced in order to force the people to change the default password. Just edit it in vars.xml and the delay should go away.

Comment: Thanks Stan,  This is so strange why there is no reference to this issue in the documentations.

Answer (score 2):

Just Like 
**Stanislav Sinyagin** edit the ***/conf/vars.xml*** and change the default password ***1234*** to new password.
this is the only way to stop that delay